# cordova file plugin could not delete a folder

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2

I am trying to delete a file from a target folder. So, initially I took a list of all files from that target folder and I checked that target file with my list of files, that condition got success.

```
fileToTrash(file) {
    console.log("going to delet a file", file);
    console.log("going to delet a file", file.audio.nativeURL);
    console.log("going to delet a file", file.audio.name);//returns a file name with .mp3 extension
    File.listDir(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, 'folder/Audios')
    .then((allFiles) => {
        // do something
        console.log("we have audio files", allFiles[0].name);
        for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
            console.log("name", allFiles[i].name);
            if (allFiles[i].name == file.audio.name) {
                console.log("condition true",allFiles[i].name, file.audio.name)
                var path = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + 'folder/Audio/';
                var filename = allFiles[i].name;
                File.removeFile( path, filename)
                .then(function (success) {
                    // success
                    console.log("success",success);
                }, function (error) {
                    // error
                    console.log(path);
                    console.log(allFiles[i].name);
                    console.log("error",error);
                });
            }
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        // do something
        console.log("file listing err", err)
    });
}
```

But on `File.removeFile(path, filename)` it moves to error block. Could someone help me?

Comment: Could you try using `=>` in `File.removeFile(path, filename)` like `File.removeFile(path, filename).then((success) => { console.log("Success",success); }, (error) => { console.log("Error.",error); })`?

Comment: No use it falls back to error block, and could you explain why do i use => this.

Comment: "moves to error block". What error does it log?

Answer (score 0):

A silly mistake in passing path `file:///storage/emulated/0/folder/Audios/`

```
 var path = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + 'folder/Audio/';
```

Correct File path contains 'Audios' and not 'Audio'.

Comment: May be you should have asked the question with the specified error. Anyways. :)